# Unity Multiple Toggle Buttons Reversing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, 3d, toggle

I am making a unity project. The situation is that I have two toggle buttons (actually more than two) toggle1 and toggle2 and two gameobjects cube1 and cube2. On start both the toggles are unchecked and gameobjects are SetActive(false). What I want is if both buttons toggle1.isOn && toggle2.isOn then cube1 SetActive and if toggle2.isOn && toggle1.isOn then cube2 SetActive according to toggle orders i.e. which toggle is selected first.
Now the problem is that When I Checked toggle1 then toggle2 in order both cubes appears and when I Checked toggle2 then toggle1  then again both cubes appears....

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ToggleToggle : MonoBehaviour {

    public Toggle toggle1;
    public Toggle toggle2;
    public GameObject cube;
    public GameObject cube2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        cube.SetActive (false);
        cube2.SetActive (false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        // Toggle1 Selected First then Toggle2
        if (toggle1.isOn && toggle2.isOn) {
            cube.SetActive (true);
        }

        // Toggle2 Selected First then Toggle1
        if (toggle2.isOn && toggle1.isOn) {
            cube2.SetActive (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your program is you forget to notify the first button pressed:

```
public int first;
void Start () {
    cube.SetActive (false);
    cube2.SetActive (false);
    first = 0;
}

    // Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!toggle1.isOn && !toggle2.isOn) {
        first = 0;
    }

    if (first == 0 && toggle1.isOn) {
        first = 1;
    }        

    if (first == 0 && toggle2.isOn) {
        first = 2;
    } 

    if (first == 1 && toggle2.isOn) {
        cube.SetActive (true);
    }

    if (first == 2 && toggle1.isOn) {
        cube2.SetActive (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Frenchy. Your Code Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to enable only **one** `GameObject` based on multiple `Toggle`s.
The first ticked determines which `GameObject`.

So you have to store the first ticked `Toggle`.

Here is an example :

```cs
public class ToggleToggle : MonoBehaviour {
/*
    public Toggle toggle1;
    public Toggle toggle2;
    public GameObject cube;
    public GameObject cube2;
*/

    public Toggle[] toggles;
    public GameObject[] cubes;

    public static Toggle firstTickedToggle;

    void Start ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cubes.Length; i++)
        {
            cubes[i].SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void OnToggleClick(Toggle toggle)
    {
        if (toggle.enabled)
        {
            if (firstTickedToggle == null)
                firstTickedToggle = toggle;

            int toggleIndex = 0; // Index of the first clicked toggle

            // Check if all toggles are ticked
            for (int i = 0; i < toggles.Length; i++)
            {
                // If one is not ticked
                if (!toggles[i].enabled)
                    return;
                if (toggles[i] == firstTickedToggle)
                    toggleIndex = i;
            }

            // Here all toggles are ticked
            cubes[toggleIndex].SetActive(true);
        }


        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < toggles.Length; i++)
            {
                // If one toggle is still ticked, don't do anything
                if (toggles[i].enabled)
                    return;
            }

            // If all toggles are unticked, remove the reference to the first ticked
            firstTickedToggle = null;
        }
    }
}
```

[All toggles need a `OnValueChanged`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQyE5.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for kind time Malphegal. But toggles are not activating cubes at all.